# Byte array Data splitting

Tags: javascript, arrays, esp32

I am reading data froma device. The Data is a serial number. I am getting it from a Byte array, and its gives me the data in HEX format. The Serial number data it gives me is as follows:
010203040506070809. How do I split the numbers and only display every second number combined together so I get 123456789?

I am using ESP32 reading from a PCB with RS485 posting to a webserver using .js.

No Idea what to do in this instance.

Comment: Data Received from the device:
[0]=H: 7e [1]=H: 1 [2]=H: dc [3]=H: 36 [4]=H: 0 [5]=H: 6 [6]=H: 36 [7]=H: 39 [8]=H: 34 [9]=H: 34 [10]=H: 34 [11]=H: 32 [12]=H: 36 [13]=H: 33 [14]=H: 30

Comment: Additional info should be in the question, not wedged into a comment. It's not clear what you're trying to show here, either only some of that data aligns with what you said you're receiving.

Comment: What do you mean by a byte array? Do you mean a Uint8Array? Or an array of numbers? There is no such thing as a byte array in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Means to extract every second number in the serial number and combine them together, you can convert the hexadecimal string into a byte array, and then iterate through every other byte and convert it back to a hexadecimal string. Finally, you can concatenate the hexadecimal strings to get the desired output.

```js
const hexString = "010203040506070809";
let serialNumber = "";

for (let i = 1; i < hexString.length; i += 2) {
  serialNumber += hexString[i];
}

console.log(serialNumber); // Output: 123456789
```

Comment: You're grabbing the wrong character.

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean,  please elaborate.

Comment: Hit the "Run code snippet button".

Comment: I forgot to initialize i=2, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: (That wouldn't be right either ;)

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. 
So the correct code would be 
for (let i = 2; i < hexString.length; i += 2) {
  serialNumber += hexString[i];
}

Comment: @GarethCarr No. What is at character 2?

Comment: Check now its correct.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Let me try this and see. I appreciate your assistance. I will revert back shortly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const s = '010203040506070809';

const n = +[...s].filter((_,i)=>i%2).join('')

console.log(n)

console.log(typeof n)
```

Comment: I mean... ok, but that's more thought for `s.replace(/0/g)` then I have the energy for.

Comment: @DaveNewton I guess it depends on whether you need `'010002'.replace(/0/g,'')` to map to `102` or `12`

Comment: Good point; `s.replace(/0(\d)/g, "$1")` then. Still easier to think about, IMO.